# incorrect display in stimulsoft reports

Tags: stimulsoft

Hi I have code like this in my application:

```
        var query = from p in db.tb_years
                    where p.id_y == Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)
                    select new
                    {
                        p.id_y,
                        p.name
                    };


        report.Load("reps\\Report.mrt");

        report.RegData("query",query);

        report.Show();
```

But it displays the entire table contents and it does not include the where clause.I have modified my code with methods like BusinessObjectsStore.Clear() & Dictionary.DataSources.Clear() but it does not make any difference. can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

If there are Business Objects in your report then you should use RegBusinessObject() method